# Drag and drop items around GridLayout - Android

Tags: android, grid-layout

I have a GridLayout with some items in it. Nothing special on it.

I just would like to know if I can drag items around and make the other items automatically arrange themselves.

It's like Android does in Jellybean if you move an icon near another icon.

Is that possible in GridLayout?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is possible with a `GridLayout`, doubt it, but [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html) is a example that looks like a `GridLayout` and implements Drag and Drop. This should solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try. Do you guys know any other object that I might use instead of GridLayout to have this functionality?

Comment: You will have to use multiple different layouts like in the link I posted

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there are many projects which could solve this slightly better than the other answer:

- See the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690568/drag-and-drop-in-gridview-in-android)
- Within this, the following projects are mentioned:

  - [PagedDragDropGrid](https://github.com/mrKlar/PagedDragDropGrid)
  - [Alternative View Drag and Drop](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/moving-views-part-2/)
  - Google Project and some other 3rd party stuff

This may help you find some stuff other than GridViews as well.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.